# data is empty from ajax request in whcms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a post request using ajax in whcms, but it seems that the data from the ajax request is null.

This is the ajax request:

```
function send_request(ticket_or_credit){
    if(ticket_or_credit == 'ticket'){
        var url = $("#ticket_action").val();
        var ticket = $("#ticket_ticket").val();
        var solution = $("#ticket_solution").val();
        whmcs_data={ request_type:ticket, solution:solution };
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(whmcs_data),
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results){
                console.log(results);
                console.log(whmcs_data);
            },
            error( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ){
                console.log( thrownError );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in my php file:

```
    $json = array("result" => "success", "message" => "Method is post", "data" => $_POST);
    echo json_encode($json);
```

The $_POST is null.

Please help me, I haven't solve this problem for how many days :(

Comment: Try just plain `data: whmcs_data`.

Comment: it won't work. :(

Comment: is `whmcs_data` has data when you do `console.log`?

Comment: Yes it has.

Object {request_type: "ticket", solution: "Downgrade your plan"}

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `contentType` and `dataType` of the ajax code just to make it default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')` and properly serialized `whmcs_data` variable. The output of your JSON.stringify is not properly serialized so I manually serialized it. for more information on ajax go to this : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and for JSON.stringify - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

try to replace variable `whmcs_data` declaration and ajax code with this:

```
whmcs_data = { 
    "request_type": ticket, 
    "solution": solution 
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: whmcs_data,
    success: function(results){
        console.log(results);
        console.log(whmcs_data);
    },
    error( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ){
        console.log( thrownError );
    }
});
```